Question about coordinates on sphere
Suppose that I have the horizontal radial projection from $S^2$ to $S^1 \times [-1,1]$ defined (outside the poles) by $P : S^2 \to S^1 \times [-1,1]$
$$P(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}},\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}},x_3\right)$$
But,  if $S^2$ and $S^1 \times [-1,1]$ are manifolds of dimension $2$, and we want to view $P$ as map between manifolds, shouldn't the map $P$ be something like $P(x_1,x_2)=(P_1(x_1,x_2),P_2(x_1,x_2))$? Because dimension $2$ means that we have $2$ variables?

The first two coordinates are actually tracing out a one-dimensional circle embedded in two-dimensional space.

This is a mapping from one surface in $\Bbb R^3$ to another, written in terms of ambient — not intrinsic — coordinates. It actually is defined on a larger domain, the complement of the $z$-axis.

And if I want to convert it to a map between manifolds? How can I do this?

Choose convenient charts … say, spherical and cylindrical coordinates. For this mapping, it will look quite simple.

I know that spherical coordinates are given by $f(\theta, \phi) = (\cos \theta \sin \phi, sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \phi)$ and cylindrical coordinates by $g(\theta, z) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, z)$ but I don't know how to continue

So to what $(\theta,z)$ does the point with coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$ map?

Ummm... I don't know

Come on! The easiest is to which $z$ it maps.
